# Why won't my eye texture mirror?

Tags: texturing, materials, modifiers, mirror

I am having this problem with the **mirror modifier** with the eyes. Blend will copy the shape, size, location, and rotation, but if I add transparency and create a texture, only the original half renders out texture, while the mirrored one doesn't register the changes.

I've tried deleting the modifier and adding another mirror modifier to no avail.

Is there a fix for this or will I have to keep duplicating the original eye and mirror it manually?

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Are you sure the texture is not on the other side of the eye for some reason ?
Otherwise can you upload a simplified version of your blend file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: Okay, so I'm currently uploading the file (1 mb is the smallest I could get it) but I've rendered the pair of eyes from all angles with the same result. I honestly don't know what the problem is. I've tried it on Blender 2.68, 2.69, 2.73, and 2.78c all with the same result. It's always the same. Maybe it's the method I'm using to make my eyes?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3671" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3671/)

Comment: the bigger question is : since you're not planning on using this model outside of Blender, why not render with Cycles ?

Comment: I did render it in cycles, but I like the look of blender render more over the realistic look of cycles.

Comment: ok, although Cycles can be customized to pretty much any graphic style by now. But if you're happy with Internal, go for it. Just know that it may be removed in the Blender 2.8x series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a procedural texture with generated coordinates. It's normal if it doesn't mirror.
If you want this blend texture to mirror while keeping the mirror modifier you'd have to use UV coordinates with an equirectangular projection and using a linear blend texture.
Or you can simply apply the mirror modifier, separate the eyes and put the origin of each one at its center.